# Where do I place npm install?

Tags: javascript, html, css, npm, npm-install

I am trying to add this frosted glass effect but I do not know where to place `npm install frosted-glass --save`

Where do I put this? I use atom code editor, I have nodejs but I just don't understand where to put this `npm install frosted-glass --save` despite all the info I looked up. I also haven't seen a question phrased exactly like mines.

Effect:[frosted glass effect github](https://github.com/adriancarriger/frosted-glass#install)

Comment: what is your project structure? can you paste it in the question.

Comment: Are you just asking where you *type* that? Into your terminal/command line, with the current working directory being the project root directory, where the `package.json` is.

Comment: to be clear: that isn't code to include in one of your code files, it's a command you type at the terminal in order to install that particular package (so that you can then access it in your JS code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed npm? take a look at this => https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-init

Try to follow these: (you need to install npm on your project, if done properly you should see `package.json` inside your project)

- Open terminal (iTerm) or Windows Terminal
- cd to the project from terminal. Example: `cd Sites/my-project`
- on this project you can type `npm i frosted-glass`

If npm confuses you, you can try to include `frosted-glass` using `<script src='https://unpkg.com/frosted-glass/dist/frostedglass.js'></script>`
See their example: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/adriancarriger/frosted-glass/tree/master/demos/vanilla/navbar?file=/index.html:364-416